# How can i take apply_filters second value? [Woocommerce]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Under woocommerce have `apply_filters` for `woocommerce_cart_product_price`

> apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_product_price', wc_price(
>   $product_price ), $product );

I created my own function and add filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_product_price', 'cart_price');
function cart_price($product_price) {
    //I want to take here $product and look product category
}
```

How can i take product information under my own **cart_price** function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Filter `woocommerce_cart_product_price` has two argument `product_price` and `product` itself, so you can you filter as

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_product_price', 'cart_price',10, 2);
function cart_price($product_price, $product ) {
  $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' ); //get the product category.
  return $product_price; //do not forgot to return product price
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get this error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function cart_price(), 1 passed in (path)/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 2 expected in`

Comment: Oh i forgot to add arg to filter. Updated answer please check.